# How to pull image so it can be analyzed for getcolors class

Tags: python, image

I am writing a program to analyze images (paintings, drawings, etc).  The `dominant_color` function should return a list of tuples `[(count, (r#, b#, g#)), ...]` sorted by `count` in descending order.

Following is the script, but I'm not certain how to correctly give `filename` a valid value.

I have tried `filename = 'path to file'`, but get a `syntax error`, unless the code is run in PyCharm.

```
def dominant_color(filename):
    #Resizing parameters
    width, height = 150,150
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image = image.resize((width, height), resample = 0)
    #Convert image to RGB
    im_rgb = im.convert('RGB')
    #Get colors from image object
    pixels = image.getcolors(width * height)
    #Sort them by count number(first element of tuple)
    sorted_pixels = sorted(pixels, key=lambda t: t[0])
    return sorted_pixels
```

#### Issues:

1. When calling `dominant_color` with a path as `filename` a `syntax error` occurs
2. The `sorted_pixels` list is not returned with the most dominant color first.

#### Expected Output:

1. Run code from the command line without an error
2. `sorted_pixels` should be returned in descending order.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use `pathlib` for finding files

- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) part of the standard library and should be used instead of `os`.
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
- The following code was successfully run in PyCharm, the command line and Jupyter.

```
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint as pp


def dominant_color(filename):

    width, height = 150, 150
    image = Image.open(p)

    image = image.resize((width, height), resample=0)
    
    # Convert image to RGB
    im_rgb = image.convert('RGB')  # the original code was incorrectly im.convert
    
    # Get colors from image object
    pixels = image.getcolors(width * height)
    
    # Sort them by count number(first element of tuple)
    sorted_pixels = sorted(pixels, key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True)

    return sorted_pixels


# p = Path.cwd().parent / 'IMG_3834.JPG'

or

# p = r'e:\PythonProjects\stack_overflow\IMG_3834.JPG'

or

p = 'e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/IMG_3834.JPG'

sorted_pixels = dominant_color(p)

pp(sorted_pixels[:5])
```

#### Output:

```
[(30, (244, 244, 244)),
 (30, (243, 243, 243)),
 (22, (242, 242, 242)),
 (15, (5, 5, 5)),
 (14, (245, 245, 245)),
```

#### From command line:

- Note how `p`, the path to the file, is built
- There are other ways to supply a list of files to a function, but that's a different question that is already covered in Stack Overflow.
- My guess would be, you're not having issues when running from PyCharm, because the image is in the same directory the function is running, which may not be the case when running the function from somewhere else.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are passing the file path as a raw string.
I mean write filepath like this:

```
filename=r'C:\deve.jpg'
```